# Placing a Transparent Java Frame Over Entire Screen

Tags: java, opengl, graphics

I'm working on a java server-style application that takes remote input and uses it to manipulate the mouse on screen. Similar to VNC, the person should be able to control the mouse as if they were working locally at the machine.

I initially planned on using the `Robot` class to manipulate the cursor, but IIRC the Robot class can only move and manipulate the cursor in the context of the application. I've heard I might need to use a java implementation of OpenGL to create a transparent window over the screen and move the mouse within that context.

What classes/libraries do I need to use so I can manipulate the mouse to control all aspects of the screen?